# blogspot.jpでのフィード情報の取得とパース

Tags: android, java

Android でアクセスをし、フィードをパースして、タイトル、日付、リンク　を取得したいです。
ライブドアブログ、FC2のブログなどでは取得できますが、blogspot.jp　でのブログで取得が行えません。

```
    try {
        Log.d("try直下", "-----");
        String mSitetitle = "";
        parser.setInput(is, null);
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Item currentItem = null;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && i < 10) {
            // Log.d("while直下","-----");
            String tag = null;
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    tag = parser.getName();
                    if ((tag.equals("title")) && (currentItem == null)) {
                        mSitetitle = parser.nextText();//サイト名を取得
                        Log.d("mSitetitle", mSitetitle);
                    }
                    if (tag.equals("item")) {
                        currentItem = new Item();//Itemクラスのインスタンスを作り、それに値を入れていく
                        currentItem.setSite(mSitetitle);

                    } else if (currentItem != null) {
                        if (tag.equals("title")) {
                            currentItem.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                            Log.d("title", parser.nextText());
                      //} else if (tag.equals("author")) {//サイト名、製作者
                            //currentItem.setSite((parser.nextText()));
                        } else if (tag.equals("pubDate")) {//日付 Sat, 31 Oct 2015 13:33:51 +0000
                            /** RSSフィードの日付フォーマットパターン */
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
                            Date formatDate = sdf1.parse(parser.nextText());  //Sat, 31 Oct 2015 13:33:51 +0000
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.setTime(formatDate);//パースした値をカレンダークラスで整形してセット
                            //タイムゾーン変更
                            cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+9:00"));
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                            String formatted = sdf2.format(cal.getTime());
                            Log.d("formatted", formatted);
                            currentItem.setDate((formatted));
                        } else if (tag.equals("date")) {//日付別バーション0
                            //2016-01-02T20:35:48+09:00
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                            Date formatDate = sdf2.parse(parser.nextText());  //Sat, 31 Oct 2015 13:33:51 +0000
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.setTime(formatDate);//パースした値をカレンダークラスで整形してセット
                            String formatted = sdf2.format(cal.getTime());
                            currentItem.setDate(formatted);
                            //currentItem.setDate((parser.nextText()));
                        } else if (tag.equals("link")) {//リンク
                            Log.d("link", parser.nextText());
                            currentItem.setLink((parser.nextText()));
                        }
                        //else if (tag.contains("link")) {//リンク
                        //  Log.d("link", parser.nextText());
                        //  currentItem.setLink((parser.nextText()));
                        //}

                    //else if (tag.equals("description")) {
                      // currentItem.setDescription(parser.nextText());
                   //}
            }
            break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                tag = parser.getName();
                if (tag.equals("item")) {
                    //mAdapter.add(currentItem);
                    items.add(currentItem);//上は　mAdapterに収納していたが、ここでは配列に収納する
                    i++;//i カウントアップ
                    Log.d("i", String.valueOf(i));
                }
                break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }//while_END
}
```

Comment: プログラムはRSSフィード向けに書かれているようですが、Atomフィードを読み込んでいる、なんてことはないですよね？ライブドアブログとblogspotはRSS/Atomどちらも配信しています。